# Пропадает внутриигровое меню при увеличении экрана

Tags: unity3d, unity3d-editor

Скрипт для вызова меню

```
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Escape))
    {
        if (!menuActive)
        {
            Debug.Log("Меню активно");
            canvas.SetActive(true);
            menuActive = true;
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("Меню отключено");
            canvas.SetActive(false);
            menuActive = false;
        }
    }
```

И скрипт самого меню

```
    public class EscMenu : MonoBehaviour
{
    public void MainMenu()
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene(0);
    }

    public void Exit()
    {
        Application.Quit();
    }
}
```

Если тестировать это на маленьком экране, то всё работает стабильно, однако при включении "Maximize On Play" и в продакшене меню не появляется!

Comment: Не помешали бы настройки Канвы. И такой нескромный вопросец: используете ли Вы `CanvasScaler`?

Comment: С ним, без него - один результат.